# Error while encrypting a file with gpg -c filename

Tags: command-line, encryption, gnupg

After installing `gpg`, when I tried to encrypt a file using it I am getting below error.

```
gpg -c test.sh

gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: error creating passphrase: Operation cancelled
gpg: symmetric encryption of `test.sh' failed: Operation cancelled
```

Is there any configuration missing after installing `gpg`?

Comment: It says cancelled by `user`, did you stop the process before completion or did so after seen error, what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: It stopped automatically i didn't stop it. Linux version:4.1.12-94.5.9.el6uek.x86_64

Comment: DId you see a dialogue box before it closed?

Comment: No nothing appears...

Comment: Having this exact same issue. Are you in an su/sudo session? I've been trying to investigate and it seems that could be part of the problem (at least in my case.)

Comment: su/sudo into another user is indeed my issue. I can use "gpg -c" with no issues as long as it's the user I'm directly logged into, but not if I switch user in that fashion. Still looking for a work around.

Comment: Yes,It works for me also , but i need to use it from another user by using sudo/su. Is there any file permission or anything we have to change to work this command